# Special tags not recognized by tag suggestion box if they contain diacritics or non-Latin characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, per-site-meta, international-sites

When [asking a question on Stack Overflow Meta en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) or on [Stack Overflow на русском Meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), the tag suggestion box doesn't seem to recognize required tags with diacritics or non-Latin characters; they're shown in blue instead of gray:

[image]

[image]

Moderator-only tags, like the `status-*` ones, aren't shown in red either:

[image]

Comment: Related in Meta SOes: [La sección “Publicaciones populares en Meta” muestra respuestas con la etiqueta \[estado-completado\], cuando no debería ser así](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3495/83) and [Etiquetas de las cuestiones migradas a Meta: usar “discusión” en lugar de “discussion”](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1391/83)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed! Tags with non-ASCII characters will be properly highlighted wherever this inline editor is used:

[image: The inline tag editor using tags with non-ASCII characters that are properly highlighted]

Please let us know if you're still seeing the incorrect highlighting being used anywhere. Thanks for reporting!